# What is the inverse of a polynomial function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, inverse

we suppose first that $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, $b>a>0$

$P$ is the polynomial function defined as  $$P(x)=2(a^3-b^3)x+(a-b)^3(x(1-x^2))$$

what is the inverse of $P(x)$ for $x\in [-1,0]$

Comment: By derivative, $P'(x)<0$ in $[-1,0]$. It does have the inverse. But maybe you need the root formula for $x=2(a^3-b^3)y+(a-b)^3(y(1-y^2))$? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%28a%5E3-b%5E3%29x%2B%28a-b%29%5E3%28x%281-x%5E2%29%29%3Dk

Comment: @user745750 please specify **context** of problem.  If this is a **contest problem**, so be it.  However, if you are posing this query in order to facilitate calculating an integral, you may be taking the **wrong approach.**  For example, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771968/f-left-x-right-x3-x-then-int-limits-12-f-left-x-rightdx-2/3772009#3772009.